# Variables inside heredoc with multiple files

Tags: bash, xml, here-document

I have a heredoc with xml content, and I add the content of another file like this:

`bar` file:

```
<bar>
  $baz
</bar>
```

the script:

```
bar=$(cat bar.xml)

# this would be the ideal, of course it doesn't work
baz=$(cat baz.xml)
#

cat << EOF > out.xml
<foo>
  $bar
</foo>
EOF
```

The output of `out.xml`:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    $baz
  </bar>
</foo>
```

---

Now I want to add a third file to the contents of `bar`:

`baz` file:

```
<baz>baz<baz>
```

so the final content of `out.xml` would be:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <baz>baz</baz>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

---

The workflow supposes that I can strip (a large) xml file into components, each one with its own components.

```
master (heredoc) xml
  ^^^
  second xml
    ^^^
    third xml
```

---

I don't know where to start as I want to keep it as simple as possible, so any help appreciated.

Comment: You should rather use an include-able preprocessor like `cpp -P` or `m4`. `envsubst` (from the `gettext-base` package) would probably also work for your very narrow XY-zied case ;-)

Comment: Thank you! I would prefer to keep it as bashist as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `envsubst` here:

```
bar=$(baz=$(cat baz.xml) envsubst '$baz' < bar.xml) envsubst '$bar' << 'EOF'
<foo>
  $bar
</foo>
EOF
```

That would make sure only `$bar`/`${bar}`/`$baz`/`${baz}` are expanded and not other expansions (`$(cmd)`, `` `cmd` ``, `$((arith))`, `${x#y}`...) or other variables like in the:

```
bar=$(cat bar.xml)
baz=$(cat baz.xml)
eval "cat << EOF
<foo>
  $bar
</foo>
EOF"
```

approach.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to combine XML documents is using *XSLT.* First, some setup:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ echo '<foo/>' > ./foo.xml
$ echo '<bar/>' > ./bar.xml
$ echo '<baz/>' > ./baz.xml
```

Then we create an XSLT file which will insert the contents of one file into an element in the source file, copying the rest of the file as-is:

```
$ cat > ./insert.xslt <<'EOF'
> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
>     <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
>         <xsl:copy>
>             <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
>             <xsl:if test="name() = $element">
>                 <xsl:copy-of select="document($file)"/>
>             </xsl:if>
>         </xsl:copy>
>     </xsl:template>
> </xsl:stylesheet>
> EOF
```

Now we can insert an arbitrary file into another:

```
$ xsltproc --output ./bar-insert.xml --stringparam file ./baz.xml --stringparam element bar ./insert.xslt ./bar.xml
$ cat ./bar-insert.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bar><baz/></bar>
```

Let's repeat to create the final file:

```
$ xsltproc --output ./foo-insert.xml --stringparam file ./bar-insert.xml --stringparam element foo ./insert.xslt ./foo.xml
$ cat ./foo-insert.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo><bar><baz/></bar></foo>
```

The nice thing about this is that it'll work on any XML files, whether they are indented, whether empty elements are collapsed, you name it.

---

It will even insert the file more than once if it's referenced more than once. For example, given people.xml:

```
<people>
    <managers>
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
        <reports>
            <insert/>
        </reports>
    </managers>
    <interns>
        <insert/>
    </interns>
</people>
```

and insert.xml:

```
<name>Abe Lincoln</name>
```

We can now put insert.xml in both locations trivially:

```
$ xsltproc --stringparam file ./insert.xml --stringparam element insert ./insert.xslt ./people.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
    <managers>
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
        <reports>
            <insert><name>Abe Lincoln</name></insert>
        </reports>
    </managers>
    <interns>
        <insert><name>Abe Lincoln</name></insert>
    </interns>
</people>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, I don't know if there's something better:

```
sed -i '/<bar>/r baz.xml' bar.xml
```

and then the heredoc:

```
bar=$(cat bar.xml)

cat << EOF > out.xml
<foo>
  $bar
</foo>
EOF
```

which outputs the desired result:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <baz>baz</baz>
  </bar>
</foo>
```